# What *is* the ngModel.$validators pipeline?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

While performing some basic research on custom client-side validation in Angular.js, I was reading the [ngModel.NgModelController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController) documentation, and found the following cryptic line:

> $setValidity(validationErrorKey, isValid);
> Change the validity state, and notifies the form.
>
> This method can be called within $parsers/$formatters. **However, if possible, please use the ngModel.$validators pipeline which is designed to call this method automatically.**

A couple of hours and many Google (and StackOverflow!) searches later, I have found nothing about this `ngModel.$validators` pipeline anywhere.  All custom validation examples use the `$parsers/$formatters` setup as below:

```
link: function (scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
    // Other necessary logic...

    ctrl.$parsers.push(function () {
        // Validation logic
        ctrl.$setValidity('validation-type', true);
    });

    ctrl.$formatters.push(function () {
        // Validation logic
        ctrl.$setValidity('validation-type', true);
    });
},
```

**Question:** The Angular documentation states that the above code is *not* the best practice, and that this mythical `ngModel.$validators` pipline is the correct way to go.  I have failed to find any information on this better practice.   How does one use `ngModel.$validators` to correctly implement this custom clientside validation?

Comment: In the same page you link, a bit lower, you will find the answer...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`$validators` are new to Angular 1.3. This blog post gives a good explanation on how to use them: http://www.yearofmoo.com/2014/09/taming-forms-in-angularjs-1-3.html#the-validators-pipeline

The basic idea is that you add a function onto `ngModel.$validators` that returns a `boolean` specifying whether the model is valid.

Then you can refrence that validator in your HTML the same way you would reference any built in validators. e.g.

```
<div ng-if="myForm.myField.$error.myValidator">
    some error message here
</div>
```